# getting rid of the title on ViewController embedded within Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

[image]

Hi guys,
I'm having a problem getting rid of the title on my ViewController that is embedded in the navigation controller and tab bar controller. I somehow don't remember how and why did I set the title on my ViewController.

Please tell me a way to fix this problem guys.
I also try

self.navigationcontroller.title = @"My Queue";

to change the name of the title, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to change it via the Storyboard?

Comment: @gimpycpu I try to go to every detail on the story of that ViewController but it doesn't seem to be in anywhere that has the word "Selecting Shop" I also try to find in the word "Selecting Shop" in the my source code by using Command+F. But still I couldn't find it anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view controller is contained within a navigation controller, it is sufficient to set the title property:

```
self.title=@"Something Title";
```

Comment: Ohhh thanks it works. I'm still curious though because I couldn't find the word "Selecting Shop" anywhere in my project both the storyboard and source codes.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to set the title is on the `navigationItem` title property:

`[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"UIViewController Title"];`